# Chrome app, Javascript, fileSystem -> createWriter -> onwriteend is called twice instead of one time (?)

Tags: javascript, filesystems, dom-events, google-chrome-app

I have the (adapted) following code:

```
    function saveFiles(saving_dir, content, name) {
      var i = 1;
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(saving_dir, function(entry) {
          entry.getFile(name, {
            create: true
          }, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
              writer.onwrite = function() {
                writer.onwrite = null;
                writer.truncate(writer.position);
              };
              writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
                console.log(i)
                i++;
                console.log('written! "' + name + '"')
                // resolve();
              };
              writer.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log('failed! "' + name + '"');
                console.log(e);
              };

              var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(content)], {
                type: 'text/javascript'
              });
              writer.write(blob);
            }, function(e) {
              trace.innerText = 'error is ' + e;
              console.log(e);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }

    saveFiles('/', 'hola', 'delete.txt');
```

And I don't know why this is executing the `onwriteend` event twice, with the `console.log(i)` giving `1` and `2`.

If I add logs in between, everything is called once except the event. Any tip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the HTML5 FileWriter truncate() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792607/using-the-html5-filewriter-truncate-method)

Comment: I've seen this is a duplicated question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792607/using-the-html5-filewriter-truncate-method, I've flagged it, but should I delete the question instead?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate - this has a different _question_ regarding `onwriteend` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You trigger a `write`, followed by `truncate` in `onwrite` listener.

Your call to `truncate` also triggers a `writeend` event, according to the [last public draft of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-writer-api-20120417/#widl-FileWriter-truncate-void-unsigned-long-long-size).